# Using ANTLR4 to generate modified code

Tags: antlr4

I'm trying to use antlr4 to parse C files using the [C.g4](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antlr/grammars-v4/master/c/C.g4) grammar.

I was wondering if there's a way to change the text inside a parse tree node and then generate a new .c file starting from the edited tree.

My goal is basically to replace all the function names with `<FUNC>`

Answer (score 1):

A function name -- looks to be an 'Identifier' -- will be represented as a TerminalNode (extends ParseTree, which is the basic parse-tree node). So, in the proper context,

```
TerminalNode id = (TerminalNode) node;
CommonToken token = (CommonToken) id.getSymbol();
token.setText("<FUNC>");
```

To record simple changes while preserving the original token text, create a custom token type (extends CommonToken) with whatever additional fields are desired.  Set a custom token factory on the lexer to use the custom tokens. See, [TokenFactory](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/runtime/Java/src/org/antlr/v4/runtime/TokenFactory.java).

Once a parse-tree is created, walk it to analyze and update the custom token fields.  Then, when walking the parse-tree to create the new '.c' file, write out whatever fields are appropriate depending on context.