# What is the ANTLR4 equivalent of a ! in a lexer rule?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I'm working on converting an old ANTLR 2 grammar to ANTLR 4, and I'm having trouble with the string rule.

```
STRING :
    '\''!
    (
        ~('\'' | '\\' | '\r' | '\n')
    )*
    '\''!
    ;
```

This creates a `STRING` token whose text contains the contents of the string, but *does not contain* the starting and ending quotes, because of the `!` symbol after the quote literals.

ANTLR 4 chokes on the `!` symbol, (`'!' came as a complete surprise to me (AC0050)`) but if I leave it off, I end up with tokens that contain the quotes, which is not what I want.  What's the correct way to port this to ANTLR 4?

Answer (score 2):

Antlr4 generally treats tokens as being immutable, at least in the sense that there is no support for a language neutral equivalent of `!`.

Perhaps the simplest way to accomplish the equivalent is:

```
string : str=STRING { Strings.unquote($str); } ; 
STRING : SQuote ~[\r\n\\']* SQuote ;
fragment SQuote : '\'' ;
```

where `Strings.unquote` is:

```
public static void unquote(Token token) {
    CommonToken ct = (CommonToken) token;
    String text = ct.getText();
    text = .... unquote it ....
    ct.setText(text);
}
```

The reason for using a parser rule is because attribute references are not (currently) supported in the lexer. Still, it could be done on the lexer rule - just would require a slight bit more effort to dig to the token.

An alternative to modifying the token text is to implement a custom token with custom fields and methods. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32520813/using-antlr4-to-generate-modified-code) if of interest.

Answer (score -1):

I believe in ANTLR4 your problem can be solved using [lexical modes and lexer commands](https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR4/Lexer+Rules).

Here is an example from there that I think does exactly what you need (although for double quotes but it's an easy fix):

```
lexer grammar Strings;
LQUOTE : '"' -> more, mode(STR) ;
WS : [ \r\t\n]+ -> skip ;

mode STR;
STRING : '"' -> mode(DEFAULT_MODE) ; // token we want parser to see
TEXT : . -> more ; // collect more text for string
```

Comment: This does not address the OP's question - how to create a token with a text value that **excludes** the quotes (that is what the Antlr2 `!` operator does). This proposed solution completely fails to accomplish that goal.