# ANTLR4: match everything between two keywords

Tags: java, parsing, antlr4

I cannot wrap my head around a *seemingly* simple problem. I have a file that has a single line header and some body:

```
File: [file name] generated by [tool name], Version [version]
...
file body
...
```

I need to extract file name, tool name and version from this file then do something with the body depending on these values. Keep in mind that names can contain arbitrary symbols including white spaces and punctuation.

The closest I came up with so far is this:

**Lexer.g4**

```
lexer grammar Lexer;

FILE    : 'File: ';
TOOL    : ' generated by ';
VERSION : ', Version';
HEND    : NL -> pushMode(BODY);
STRING  : .+?;
NL      : '\r'? '\n' | '\r';

mode BODY;
TEXT    : .*? EOF -> popMode;
```

**Parser.g4**

```
parser grammar Parser;

options {
  tokenVocab = Lexer;
}

content : header HEND body;

header  : file tool version;
file    : FILE STRING+;
tool    : TOOL STRING+;
version : VERSION STRING+;

body    : TEXT;
```

The only problem with this parser is that it represents file name, tool name and version as a list of one-character tokens instead of a single token with the whole string. Removing '+' in STRING+ rules leads to a total misfire.

Comment: Isn't ANTLR a bit overkill to parse a single line? Perhaps it would be easier to use `substring()` and `indexOf(" generated by ")` etc.

Comment: This is just a _very_ simplified example. In fact header has much more than a single line; body has to be parsed, too.

Comment: By insisting on a particular form of token matching, you are effectively mixing syntactic matching and semantic presentation - two concerns that Antlr4 wants to separate - and should be separated. There is no simple way to do what you are asking. There may be an indirect way using [Rule Attribute Definitions](https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR4/Parser+Rules#ParserRules-RuleAttributeDefinitions), but that is uncertain.  This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32549905/what-is-the-antlr4-equivalent-of-a-in-a-lexer-rule) might also help.

Comment: I believe your answer to [that question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32549905/what-is-the-antlr4-equivalent-of-a-in-a-lexer-rule) is not exactly the simplest one; see my answer there. This is what makes me think there should be something simpler in my case, too. After all, all I need is basically to match everything between two "keywords" as a token